# Unable to set SimpleTableDataAdapter inside Fragment

Tags: android

I am using the following dependencies for TableView.

```
compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0'
```

But I am unable to set SimpleTableDataAdapter inside Fragment.

```
tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(this, body));
```

I have tried using the following, but none works.

```
tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data));

tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), data));
```

Getting the following error when I am using **getActivity()**

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'SimpleTableDataAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, java.lang.String[])
```

Comment: That constructor expects a `String[][]`, not a `String[]`. https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView/blob/master/tableview/src/main/java/de/codecrafters/tableview/toolkit/SimpleTableDataAdapter.java#L32

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. But if I do the following

`String[][] data = {j,name,email,phone};`

I am getting the following error

`Incompatible types.
Required:
java.lang.String[]
Found:
java.lang.String`

Comment: Not really. I have no idea what the received data is, or what you're trying to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not of the **getActivity()**
The constructor expects two dimensional array.

```
 final String[][] DATA_TO_SHOW = { { "This", "is", "a", "test" },
        { "and", "a", "second", "test" } };
tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), DATA_TO_SHOW));
```

not a single dimen string array.