# How to insert ListView data into TableView?

Tags: android, tableview

I am trying to insert data from my database into a table view layout. I have a file called `getData` which accesses my database and stores all the information into an array, which you can find below:

```
public class GetValence {
Connection connect;
String ConnectionResult = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;

public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground() {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try
    {
        ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
        connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
        if (connect == null)
        {
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Change below query according to your own database.
            String query = "select * from cc_valence";
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("VALENCE_NAME"));

                datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("VALENCE_UNIT_PRICE"));

                datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("VALENCE_RANGE"));

                datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("VALENCE_SUPPLIER"));

                datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("VALENCE_SIZE"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }
```

And now i need to insert this data into my `Table_test.java` file for it to display on my tableview which you can find below:

```
public class TableTest extends AppCompatActivity {
static String[] spaceProbeHeaders={"Name","Price","Range","Supplier","Size"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TableView<String[]> tableView = (TableView<String[]>) findViewById(R.id.tableView);

    tableView.setHeaderBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
    tableView.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(this,spaceProbeHeaders));
    tableView.setColumnCount(5);
    List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;
    GetValence mydata =new GetValence();
    MyData= mydata.doInBackground();
    String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","RANGE","SUPPLIER","SIZE" };


    tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(TableTest.this, fromwhere));
}
```

However i get `Cannot resolve constructor SimpleTabledataAdapter`

Comment: The constructor for simpletabledataAdapter expects two dimensional array.

Comment: @Sylwek so how would you convert this into 2d array

Comment: Im also not sure how to convert to 2 dimensional array

Comment: see the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605283/unable-to-set-simpletabledataadapter-inside-fragment